# How do I get Crystal Reports in VS 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have an issue with VS 2012 i.e. I want to create a report e.g. result of a particular student. I have searched a lot then I came to know I have to install SAP Crystal report, and I have done so. But still no Crystal Report in the Toolbox, there are only two items named: Report, Report Wizard. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Stop indenting text - pay attention to the preview in your editor. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Agreed - I've rolled back to your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAP Crystal Reports Developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio is avalable now

Download http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074

Answer (score 3):

CrystalReports for VS2012 is not available until late Q1 2013.

You can read more about this [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2012/09/20/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio--2012-support-update)

> Our development teams are hard at work updating SAP Crystal Reports to support Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5, with plans to make this update available in late Q1 2013. Dates are of course subject to change, based on product readiness.

Comment: But I have a question. What if I want to use the crystal runtime to only view reports on the production server,not to create them. I don't care if they work in VS 2012 and my application uses .Net 4.0. I only want to view them. I think in that case I should be able to use the Crystal Redistributable for .Net 4.0,right?

Answer (score 1):

[Old Link](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074) >> Download link has been expired

New dowload link is :

[Download from here](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html) >> From Original web site

or get Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio - 2012
diretctly from

[Here](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe) 291 MB