# Crystal reports with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I'm using crystal reports for creating my reports. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I use VS2010 to create the reports then I add them to the solution in VS2012. The problem is that I'm getting an exception bobj undefined when I run the report under VS2012. Is is related to the fact that the project is running under VS2012 or is it caused by another thing? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm guessing it is VS2012, based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720386/how-do-i-get-crystal-reports-in-vs-2012

Comment: CR SP5 that supports VS2012, Win8 and SQL 2012 fully released
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 5):

SAP Crystal Reports Developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio is finally avalable, so you can create them in vs 2012.

Download http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074

Answer (score 1):

By following below URL you may find the perfect answer for your question.
This is not my experience, and I had found this answer while I search for Crystal report integration basics with VS 2012.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695587/Beginners-tutorial-on-how-to-load-Crystal-Reports

Good Luck & Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not VS2012 problem.
Crystal reports runtime is installed but it's files are not reached by browser.
You installed your application in a website different from Default Website.. did you?
  Look at the Solution at the end of this post.

### Analyze the problem

It's possible to analyze the problem, and find a **403 (Forbidden)** error

- using **client tools** (debug window of browser)

`GET     http://someServer:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js 403 (Forbidden)

GET http://someServer:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css 403 (Forbidden)`

- or **server tool** (IIS log , on WIN2003 is placed in `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC###\`).

> 2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!
>   2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!

### Cause the problem

- In both cases i found that `crv.js` and `style.css` some files were not served;
- these files are placed by CR installer in `wwwroot\aspnet_client` folder, but for some reasons they cannot be reached;
- In my case the reason is that i create a **different website (port 20080) and aspnet_client folder is not placed inside that website**

I can see that you use different versions of software and different configurations, but **i think you have the same problem**.

### Solution

The solution is to work on IIS  this way:

- **Copy `aspnet_client` folder** from `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder to the **new website root folder**.

or (this one is better)

- **Create a virtual directory** called `aspnet_client` that points to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` **inside the new website**